# Can i setup Robolectric in its own module

Tags: android, gradle, robolectric

Is is possible to setup robolectric in its own module and add it as a dependency to my project? I can add it to my project module fine but id prefer if it was in its own module. Ive created a javaLibrary module and added the following code to the gradle build script

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    }
dependencies {
    //Prior to AS 0.5.9: classpath 'org.robolectric.gradle:gradle-android-test-plugin:0.9.+'
    classpath 'org.robolectric.gradle:gradle-android-test-plugin:0.10.0'

    //previous plugin >> classpath 'com.novoda.gradle:robolectric-plugin:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-test' //previously >> apply plugin: 'robolectric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.irishtimes.newsapp.tests"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

sourceSets {
    androidTest.setRoot('src/tests') //note that this is androidTest instead of instrumentTest
    }
}


dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    //include the stable robolectric 2.3 library
    androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'
}

//only include files that are suffixed with Test.class and set the max heap size
androidTest {
    include '**/*Test.class'
    maxHeapSize = "2048m"
}
```

Ive also added a blank manifest file and a dummy test in a src/tests/java. In my previous setup when i run ./gradlew test, my tests would run and id get feedback. Now when i run the same command my build script runs but it does not pick up my tests at all. If anyone has any reference to tutorials or advice or a quick solution that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible with a different plugin. Plugin supported by robolectric do not support this.

Plugin can be found here https://github.com/novoda/gradle-android-test-plugin
A ready to use example can be found here https://github.com/nenick/android-gradle-template

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run tests from a separate folder, but not necessarily a separate module, I have had some success with the [Android Studio Unit Test Plugin](https://github.com/evant/android-studio-unit-test-plugin) along with [this gradle plugin](https://github.com/JCAndKSolutions/android-unit-test).